# Passing data to other classes via getter/setter

Tags: java, encapsulation, getter-setter

I'm having issues passing data from a GUI to other classes. Everything is initialized in the GUI and then from there the data is passed to another class where additional changes may take place: (simplified and missing parts for compilation)

```
class GUI extends JFrame {
final Configuration conf = new Configuration();

GUI() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {

    //Setup default values
    conf.expectFires(false);
    conf.expectRain(false);
    conf.expectDisaster(true);

    JComboBox<String> seasonTypes = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall"});

    seasonTypes.setSelectedIndex(0);
    conf.setSeason(seasonTypes.getItemAt(seasonTypes.getSelectedIndex()));

    //Action listener for dynamic changes to whatever is selected
    seasonTypes.addActionListener(e -> {
        String season = seasonTypes.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (!season.equals(""))
            conf.setSeason(season);
    });

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The data is supposed to be saved to my configuration class which is a getter/setter class. I'm unable to retrieve any data unless I set it within the same class:

Main class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    //code for GUI not included but pretend the GUI is called here

    //data does not come out it's basically unset.
    System.out.println("Data from GUI: [season]"+ conf.getSeason()+ " Season expectations: " + conf.expectations());

    //yet this works just fine. 
    conf.setSeason("Summer");
    System.out.println("What's the last season set?: " + conf.getSeason()); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are creating two instances of your `Configuration` class. One in the `GUI` and one in your `Main` class. These are not shared.

If you want to use the `Configuration` from the `GUI` try adding a getter for your `Configuration` within the `GUI` class

```
public Configutation getConfig()
{
     return conf;
}
```

then in your main try:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //code for GUI not included but pretend the GUI is called here
    // Assuming something like:
    GUI gui = new GUI();

    Configuration conf = gui.getConfig();

    System.out.println("Data from GUI: [season]"+ conf.getSeason()+ " Season expectations: " + conf.expectations());
    }
}
```

Another option would be to create your `Configuration` as a Singleton - then you get the same instance rather then instantaiting a new one each time. [Here is an example of how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)